# Setup docker-compose to make OAuth flow work

Tags: docker, oauth, oauth-2.0, docker-compose

I am trying to setup docker compose for local development, which consist from two services. OAuthServer and ClientApp.

The issue is that communication on host machine must work.
Both services are accessible on localhost:3000 (ClientApp)  and localhost:4000 (OAuthServer). That is simple.

But also ClientApp must be able to communicate with OAuthServer directly. And that’s where the problem is. Standard OAuth flow does expect that the ClientApp will be always communicating with OAuthServer on same url.

The URL for ClientApp  reach OAuthServer is `oauthserver:4000`.

One possible solution is to use `network_mode: host`, but unfortunately I am on Mac OS and [it doesn’t seems to work](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1031).

Can you please suggest any solution?

```
version: '3'
services:
  clientapp:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - oauthserver
    environment:
      - AUTH_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  oauthserver:
    image: myauthserver
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5432
```

Comment: Is the actual application a browser app (`clientapp` is something like an `npm run dev` server and the actual code runs in a browser), or is this a server-to-server flow?

Comment: it is node application using [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/) with [oauth2 strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-oauth2/).